# Create reusable functions bash

Tags: shell-script, curl

I have the following the curl command :-

```
curl --cert certificate_file.pem:password -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{somedata}'
```

below part of curl would be common

> curl --cert certificate_file.pem:password

How can I make it reusable and call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even use an alias for that, since the first part remains constant.

```
alias mycurl='curl --cert certificate_file.pem:password'
```

If you insist on a function, this could work:

```
function mycurl()
{
    curl --cert certificate_file.pem:password "$@"
}
```

Both can now be invoked this way:

```
mycurl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{somedata}'
```